# Angular 6.1.2 PWA not working

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I tried all the solutions on the internet on how to add PWA to an Angular project, but still in Chrome Dev Tools, there are no service worker registered.

I did run `ng add @angular/pwa`, with `ng build --prod` and `http-server -o` and still no service worker registered. It also does not add a *@angular/service-worker* package and also no *Manifest.json* file like it should as indicated all over the internet.

I also tried creating a new project with PWA pre-installed with `ng new myProject --service-worker`, also not working.

I even tried registering the service working like below:

`if ( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
  });`

A side note: When I run `ng add @angular/pwa` I get a message "Path '/ngsw-config.json' already exist", so I found out that file is under *@schematics* package. The script only adds a *@angular/pwa* package, which does not corrolate with the Angular PWA docs.

---

Here is my environment :

```
Angular 6.1.2
Angular CLI: 6.1.3
Node 8.11.3
NPM  5.6.0
```

---

What do I need to do to get a plain PWA Angular project?

Comment: Yup, unfortunately there seem to be quite a few bugs recently in the `cli` :( Ran into this myself as well and have not found any _easy_ solution. Am working on other parts of the project meanwhile :)

Comment: I have an empty base PWA here if doing a compare with yours might help. https://github.com/ng-chicago/AngularBasePWA

Comment: Note the creation steps I took are in the ReadMe.md

Comment: Thanks @Mathias, I did test your project, but with no success, the site work, but no service worker and the following error: 'SecurityError: Only secure origins are allowed'. I guess it's not a good time to start PWA apps at the moment, so back to hybrid apps we go

Comment: No, it works perfectly. And yours may also. Testing a PWA locally is challenging and not recommended by many because the was the service worker works. Here is that project deployed to a server. Try running the Audit tools. https://angularbasepwa.glitch.me/

Comment: Do a build of your project and deploy it to a regular HTTP server. Then test. Https://Glitch.me is free and quick

Comment: I mean a HTTPS server

Comment: I deployed it to a HTTPS server and it worked, thanks @Mathias. So that caused me to dig a little deeper and try to find out where the problem lies. It is the new version of `@angular/pwa` that has a few bugs. So running `ng add @angular/pwa@0.6.8` worked perfectly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is the new version of `@angular/pwa` package that has a few bugs. So running `ng add @angular/pwa@0.6.8` worked perfectly for me.

To test the service worker locally: If you have Firebase added to your project (hosting), you can run `ng build --prod` and then `firebase serve`. When you don't have Firebase, you can run `ng build --prod`, cd into the dist folder (depending on your config) and then run `http-server -o`. If you don't have `http-server` module, install it by running `npm i -g http-server`

Comment: All examples are with ng build --prod. How can I make it work with ng build?

Comment: @EroStefano you can just leave out the `--prod` or add `-c=stage` for stage environment, if it's set up

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Angular Console: https://angularconsole.com/

It abstracts away many of the need to know logic that the cli has.

It's in beta but it should help you create the base for your PWA. Give it a try it's build from the Nrwl Team that also builds Nx which is an enhancement to the angular/cli using schematics

Comment: Thanks @Nico for the suggestion. I did try the Angular Console, but it gives the exact same outcome

Comment: Did you try creating a new project using Angular Console and adding the pwa schematics to it?

Comment: But we have older large projects and we cannot create new project on every version of cli. PWA is still very unusable.  PWA is killing a lot of time with no result. I will try PWA in version 10, for now I have enough of non-functional PWA. It is beautiful - they close issues of PWA without solution and PWA works just on empty new project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was than this command:
ng add @angular/pwa

didn't add module @angular/pwa to package.json dependencies.

I decided it so.

First I run ng add @angular/pwa
Then I did:
npm install @angular/pwa

And it all works!